# ASP.NET MVC5 template missing in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

About a month ago, I installed Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3) Professional on my machine, but didn't activate it back then. Now since the 'trial version' has expired, I entered a genuine license key to unlock the software, which worked perfectly fine - however now the ASP.NET MVC5 empty web template seems missing. I tried to repair my installation, but no luck with that. What could cause this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked here? you can get more frameworks here

[image]